Compiling my Qt project with qmake (via Qt Creator) does not recompile my static libraries when changed
I am making a game C++ project with Qt. As it grew, I wanted to split it into multiple static libraries.
Now I have a bunch of *.pro files and one subdirs .pro file to connect them.
As I did this, it seems to my that it does not recompile everything, when I did some change. To be honest, I'm not exactly sure what would be the correct way to tell qmake that.
I think it may be either the depends attribute in the subdirs file or the DEPENDPATH variable, and I don't think I have fully understood how the DEPENDPATH variable should be used correctly.
May someone explain this to me (or tell if my issue should be solved completely different)?
My project structure looks like this:
(BasicLib is a dynamically linked library, but all others are statically linked)
FactoryGameSubdirs.pro:
TEMPLATE = subdirs

SUBDIRS = \   # sub-project names
        DataAccess \
        GUI \
        GameLogic \
        MapItems \
        Common \
        FactoryGame

# where to find the sub projects - give the folders
Common.subdir = FactoryGame/Code/Common
MapItems.subdir = FactoryGame/Code/MapItems
DataAccess.subdir = FactoryGame/Code/DataAccess
GameLogic.subdir = FactoryGame/Code/GameLogic
GUI.subdir = FactoryGame/Code/GUI
FactoryGame.subdir = FactoryGame

# what subproject depends on others
GUI.depends = MapItems

GameLogic.depends = MapItems
GameLogic.depends = Common

MapItems.depends = Common

FactoryGame.depends = Common
FactoryGame.depends = MapItems
FactoryGame.depends = DataAccess
FactoryGame.depends = GameLogic
FactoryGame.depends = GUI`

GameLogic.pro:
QT -= gui

TEMPLATE = lib
CONFIG += staticlib

CONFIG += c++20

DEFINES += QT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x060000    # disables all the APIs deprecated before Qt 6.0.0

# sources and headers removed here as not important...

# Default rules for deployment.
unix {
    target.path = $$[QT_INSTALL_PLUGINS]/generic
}
!isEmpty(target.path): INSTALLS += target

DESTDIR = $$PWD/../../bin
OBJECTS_DIR = $$PWD/../../bin/.obj
MOC_DIR = $$PWD/../../bin/.moc
RCC_DIR = $$PWD/../../bin/.rcc

INCLUDEPATH += ../
INCLUDEPATH += ../../../../BasicLib
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../GameLogic`

MapItems.pro:
QT -= gui
QT += concurrent

TEMPLATE = lib
CONFIG += staticlib

CONFIG += c++20

DEFINES += QT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x060000    # disables all the APIs deprecated before Qt 6.0.0

LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../bin -lBasicLib
LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../bin -lCommon

# sources and headers

# Default rules for deployment.
unix {
    target.path = $$[QT_INSTALL_PLUGINS]/generic
}
!isEmpty(target.path): INSTALLS += target

DESTDIR = $$PWD/../../bin
OBJECTS_DIR = $$PWD/../../bin/.obj
MOC_DIR = $$PWD/../../bin/.moc
RCC_DIR = $$PWD/../../bin/.rcc

INCLUDEPATH += ../
INCLUDEPATH += ../../../../BasicLib

DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../Common`

GUI.pro:
greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 5): QT += widgets

TEMPLATE = lib
CONFIG += staticlib

CONFIG += c++20

DEFINES += QT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x060000    # disables all the APIs deprecated before Qt 6.0.0

QT += core gui

LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../bin -lBasicLib

# sources and headers

# Default rules for deployment.
unix {
    target.path = $$[QT_INSTALL_PLUGINS]/generic
}
!isEmpty(target.path): INSTALLS += target

DESTDIR = $$PWD/../../bin
OBJECTS_DIR = $$PWD/../../bin/.obj
MOC_DIR = $$PWD/../../bin/.moc
RCC_DIR = $$PWD/../../bin/.rcc

INCLUDEPATH += ../
INCLUDEPATH += ../../../../BasicLib
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../GUI`

DataAccess.pro:
QT += gui

TEMPLATE = lib
CONFIG += staticlib

CONFIG += c++20

DEFINES += QT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x060000    # disables all the APIs deprecated before Qt 6.0.0

# sources and headers

# Default rules for deployment.
unix {
    target.path = $$[QT_INSTALL_PLUGINS]/generic
}
!isEmpty(target.path): INSTALLS += target

DESTDIR = $$PWD/../../bin
OBJECTS_DIR = $$PWD/../../bin/.obj
MOC_DIR = $$PWD/../../bin/.moc
RCC_DIR = $$PWD/../../bin/.rcc

INCLUDEPATH += ../`


Common.pro:
QT -= gui

TEMPLATE = lib
CONFIG += staticlib

CONFIG += c++20

DEFINES += QT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x060000    # disables all the APIs deprecated before Qt 6.0.0

# sources and headers

# Default rules for deployment.
unix {
    target.path = $$[QT_INSTALL_PLUGINS]/generic
}
!isEmpty(target.path): INSTALLS += target

DESTDIR = $$PWD/../../bin
OBJECTS_DIR = $$PWD/../../bin/.obj
MOC_DIR = $$PWD/../../bin/.moc
RCC_DIR = $$PWD/../../bin/.rcc

INCLUDEPATH += ../`


Currently I am changing a lot of stuff in the GUI library, so here I currently noticing the issue the most (but probably the other libs are also affected). I see that with "compile and run" (Ctrl+R) it simply not using the new code, but the code before. The only workaround I have found is to recompile the complete project, but that very annoying and takes much longer to compile.
